# How to apply border on input?

Tags: jquery

I'm amazed this works: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MQb2P/)

```
<span>
<input type="checkbox" />
</span>

span{
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

But this doesn't work: [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/u6v9n/)

```
<input type="checkbox" />

$('input').wrap('<span />').css('border','1px solid red');
```

Comment: have you inspected the element? You're applying the border to the `<input>` instead to the `<span>`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to apply the border on `<span>` element, not `<input>` so you can traverse up one level using **[.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/)**:

```
$('input').wrap('<span />').parent().css('border','1px solid red');
```

**[Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/u6v9n/1/)**